# How do I make a client-side only component for GatsbyJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

How do I create a component for Gatsby that will load on the client-side, not at build time?

I created this one and it renders with `gatsby develop` but not with the rendered server-side rendering

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import adapter from 'axios-jsonp';

export default class Reputation extends React.Component<{}, { reputation?: number }> {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {};
    }

    async componentDidMount() {
        const response = await axios({
            url: 'https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users/23528?&site=stackoverflow',
            adapter
        });
        if (response.status === 200) {
            const userDetails = response.data.items[0];
            const reputation = userDetails.reputation;
            this.setState({
                reputation
            });
        }
    }

    render() {
        return <span>{ this.state.reputation?.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",") }</span>
    }
}
```

Comment: So, you want to render it, only at the client side?

Comment: @Peter yep - i dont want to burn the value in when deploying

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want the component to be bundled in the main js file at build time, use `loadable-components`

> Install `loadable-components` and use it as a wrapper for a component that wants to use a client-side only package. [docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/using-client-side-only-packages/)

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Loadable from "@loadable/component";

const LoadableReputation = Loadable(() =>
  import("../components/Reputation")
);

const Parent = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <LoadableReputation />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Parent;
```

Answer (score 1):

before render this component, make sure you have a window, to detect if there is a window object. I would write a hook for that:

```
function hasWindow() {
  const [isWindow, setIsWindow] = React.useState(false);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    
    setIsWindow(true);

    return ()=> setIsWindow(false);
  }, []);

  return isWindow;
}
```

In the parent component check if there is a window object:

```
function Parent(){
  const isWindow = hasWindow();
  if(isWindow){
    return <Reputation />;
  }
  return null;
}
```